# Failure to obtain JNDI administered objects MQ in IIB application Windows server

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, jndi, initial-context

I am working on my local windows IIB/MQ server. What I am trying to do is place a message on JMSOutput queue. 
For that, I have created JMS Administered Object by creating an initial context factory and within it I have created Destination Queue and Connection Factory using file system option. I got a .binding file created in the Provider_URL path specified below.

In JMS Output node proprerties, I have set the JMS Provider name to

> Websphere MQ

and initial context factory to

> com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory

All the other options are unfilled.

Please note that the JMSADmin.config file has the following uncommented properties:

> PROVIDER_URL=file:/C:/JNDI
>   INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory

Now when I try to put a message on JMS Output node, I get the following exception:

> ExceptionList
>       RecoverableException
>               File:CHARACTER:F:\build\S1000_slot1\S1000_P\src\DataFlowEngine\MessageServices\ImbDataFlowNode.cpp
>               Line:INTEGER:1251
>               Function:CHARACTER:ImbDataFlowNode::createExceptionList
>               Type:CHARACTER:ComIbmJMSClientOutputNode
>               Name:CHARACTER:test#FCMComposite_1_4
>               Label:CHARACTER:test.JMS Output
>               Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
>               Severity:INTEGER:3
>               Number:INTEGER:2230
>               Text:CHARACTER:Node throwing exception
>               Insert
>                       Type:INTEGER:14
>                       Text:CHARACTER:test.JMS Output
>               RecoverableException
>                       File:CHARACTER:JMSClientErrors.java
>                       Line:INTEGER:771
>                       Function:CHARACTER:JMSClientErrors:handleJNDIException()
>                       Type:CHARACTER:
>                       Name:CHARACTER:
>                       Label:CHARACTER:
>                       Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
>                       Severity:INTEGER:3
>                       Number:INTEGER:4640
>                       Text:CHARACTER:Failure to obtain JNDI administered objects
>                       Insert
>                               Type:INTEGER:5
>                               Text:CHARACTER:Broker 'LOCALBK10'; Execution Group 'Test'; Message Flow 'test'; Node 'ComIbmJMSClientOutputNode' 
>                       Insert
>                               Type:INTEGER:5
>                               Text:CHARACTER:com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory
>                       Insert
>                               Type:INTEGER:5
>                               Text:CHARACTER:
>                       Insert
>                               Type:INTEGER:5
>                               Text:CHARACTER:
>                       Insert
>                               Type:INTEGER:5
>                               Text:CHARACTER:Hello
>                       Insert
>                               Type:INTEGER:5
>                               Text:CHARACTER: Cause:java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
>                       Insert
>                               Type:INTEGER:5
>                               Text:CHARACTER: , Failure to obtain JNDI administered objects

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any special reason why you want to use JMS Output node? If you use the MQ Output node, you do not need the JNDI configuration.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann Actually I am trying to reproduce an issue that we are facing at Test environment. I dont have the access to it so I am trying to replicate the issue which is with JMS output node and see what is wrong in that particular scenario. But for that I need to have JMS output node working.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Did you try what I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Towards the end of above stack trace you see this

> Cause:java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol

This is because you did not set the value for property `Location JNDI bindings`. It has to have the same value as configured in `JMSAdmin.config`, i.e. `file:/C:/JNDI`.